# Reference field returning NULL in Test class only

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, failing-tests

We are facing a very strange issue when writing proper unit test using asserts.

We have two objects which have logical link with a field. So, we wrote a batch class to relate those two objects using a newly created lookup field. Batch is working fine and tested in all possible ways.

Problem starts here, when we write test class and run the batch in test class (created set up data and `Test.startTest()` etc.), we are getting that lookup field `null` in Test `assert`. But in main class system debug the lookup field is filled correctly. Even running the batch class through test class we are getting correct values in debug. But in Test asserts, it is `NULL`.

Data is created as:

```
    for(integer i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        AccId__c aSID = new AcId__c();
        aSID.name = 'SID'+i;
        aSID.OwnerUser_SID__c = '1234567'+i;
        aSID.OwnerUser_Email_Address__c = 'cont'+i+'@xyz.com';
        aSid.OwnerUser_SID__c = 'ousidlead'+i;  
        aSID.Lead__c = null;
        SIDlist.add(aSID);
    }    
    insert SIDlist;

    for(integer i=0; i<5; i++)
    {    
        Lead ld = new Lead();
        ld.firstname = 'AngryLead';            
        ld.lastname = 'Cont'+i;            
        ld.title = 'CEO';
        ld.Email= 'cont'+i+'@xyz.com';
        ld.company = 'Salesforce';
        leadList.add(ld);
    }
    insert leadList;




   //This is how we are asserting:-



System.debug(' @@===> Total Ids '+acidIds);
    test.startTest();
        BatchLinkLeadToAcID bat = new BatchLinkLeadToAcID(); 
        database.executebatch(bat);

        System.schedule('Sync Leads - Hourly', '0 0 * * * ?', new BatchLinkLeadToAcID());
        List<Lead> leadListQueriedIn = [select id,Email,OwnerUser_SID__c from Lead where id in:leadIds];

        System.debug(' in Context Lead ==> '+leadListQueriedIn);
        list<AcID__c > newSIDlistIn = [select id,OwnerUser_SID__c,Lead__c, OwnerUser_Email_Address__c from AcID__c where id IN: acidIds];
        System.debug(' In Context Sid ==> '+newSIDlistIn);

    test.stopTest();

    List<Lead> leadListQueried = [select id,Email,OwnerUser_SID__c from Lead where id in:leadIds];
    System.debug(' Out of Context Lead ==> '+leadListQueried);

    System.debug(' >>=====> Access '+AcID__c.Lead__c.getDescribe().isAccessible());
    System.debug(' >>=====> Access '+AcID__c.Lead__c.getDescribe());

    List<AcID__c > newSIDlist = [select id,OwnerUser_SID__c,Lead__c, OwnerUser_Email_Address__c from AcID__c where id IN: acidIds];
    System.debug(' Out of Context Sid ==> '+newSIDlist);

    for(integer i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        system.assertequals(leadListQueried[i].OwnerUser_SID__c, newSIDlist[i].OwnerUser_SID__c ); // PASS
        system.assertequals(leadListQueried[i].id, newSIDlist[i].Lead__c ); // FAIL
        System.assert(newSIDlist[i].Lead__c != null); //FAIL
    }
```

We tested creating same records by UI as well. It is working. It is only failing in Test class. What can be the reason? Code run in production without any issue but above specific assert related to reference field are failing.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: how many records are in batch? as far as I know SF executes only first batch from batch job

Comment: Total 5 records @kurunve

Comment: and Test.stopTest() is used as well?

Comment: Those asserts can only occur after Test.stopTest(). If that's what you're doing, have you tried changing `aSID.Lead__c = null;` to `aSID.Lead__c.isEmpty();` or just omitting it entirely?

Comment: Of course! Test.stopTest() is there :D. @kurunve `aSID.Lead__c.isEmpty()` must have Id actually it should not be empty or null.

Comment: @Ashwani can you execute single execute method from batch class in test method and see if that works (not like batch job, but as  like regular method). If that fail -- then there is an issue in code. if no -- then your execute method is not executed in tests.

Comment: @crmprogdev code works everywhere except the test method. Even running batch from test method it show id populated in system debug written in batch but no in test method. Both way explicit query record in testmethod even doesnt work. Unexpected!

Comment: @kurunve code works everywhere except the test method. Even running batch from test method it show id populated in system debug written in batch but no in test method. Both way explicit query record in testmethod even doesnt work. Unexpected!

Comment: this may or may not be your issue but I find that adding `order by` to the testmethod SOQL can return results in a predictable manner so you are asserting results versus testmethod mocked sobject lists in a correlated way

Comment: @crop1645 yes I agree with you. But there will not be any empty field. This is one of the case.

Comment: does the assertion fail on the 0th or later row? I find it helpful to include the index `[i]` as part of the 3rd argument to `system.assertEquals(..)`

Comment: @crop1645 It is failing for all records where Lead__c is checked. I get assert failed, expected 00Q0000000eryeWeS actual null.

Comment: It seems to me like your code snippets are incomplete.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes it is not complete code but has major snippet. I have added few more lines of the test class.

Comment: Why are you scheduling it instead of just executing it. Are you getting `AsyncApexJob` records?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Batch class implements `Batchable` and `schedulable` interface. However, removing the schedule statement not effecting the result.

Comment: I'm saying you should call `executeBatch`.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You mean to say I do it like `BatchLinkLeadToAcID bat = new BatchLinkLeadToAcID();  bat.execute(null, recordList)`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson `BatchLinkLeadToAcID bat = new BatchLinkLeadToAcID(); 
        database.executebatch(bat);` perfectly running batch. Class coverage is 94%. But assert is getting failed. Weird thing.

Comment: Do you run the batch twice in your test? It looks like you're trying to run it right after `// Then we run a batch` and also between `Tets.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()`

Comment: @Novarg No, running it only once. Updated answer for clarification

Comment: Don't we need to see the batch itself to have any hope of helping you? It's unclear how there records are supposed to get linked.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36151/discussion-on-question-by-ashwani-reference-field-returning-null-in-test-class-o).